# How to give a JS command to put a cursor inside an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a simple text input field:

> ```
> <input value="Hello">
> ```

I want to write a JS code that place the focus on the input box and put a cursor inside.

I tried to use focus() in JQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $($('input')[0]).click(function() {
      this.focus();
   })
})
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to put the focus on an element that you have just clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access `input` element using a simple `selector`: `$('input')`. Then, you have to bind an event handler to the `focus` JavaScript event.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('input').focus();
});
```

Comment: This will cause the first `input` element in the document to get the focus. You should use a more specific selector in case it turns out that the first one is not the one that needs the focus.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I know this. I used this selector only for this example. OP then will adapt to its code.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is not needed for such a simple issue. Just access the element via a valid selector and call its `.focus()` method.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  document.querySelector("input[value='Hello']").focus();
});
```

```html
<input value="Hello">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use css instead

```
input:focus { 
    background-color: #hex_code;
}
```

Comment: How can you bind `.focus` event when page is loaded using css?

Comment: This will not cause the element to get the focus. It will style it once it has the focus.